# Esper - Is there any open source RDBMS based Event Store available?

Tags: events, time-series, esper

We are using Esper CEP engine (basic edition ) for our BI solution.  I would also like to persist events to Oracle. Esper has a separate enterprise product EsperHA which provides this functionality.  Esper HA is full blown HA product. We just need the event persistence so that that data could be used by other application directly or via Esper. Is there any java based open source implementation for EsperHA type functionality available? I could not find one. Basically I am looking for RDBMS based time Series database which transparently provides event persistence (without writing any sql queries/embedding sql like in esper EPL) for Esper.

Answer (score 0):

Why not independently of Esper store events also to Oracle database using JDBC for example?
When you say you just need "event persistence" then a simple JDBC write of events with a timestamp column would seem to do, or am I missing an unstated requirement here?

Comment: Storing events to database and constructing event stream from database (for replay purpose – particularly for historical reports) is done transparently by Esper HA.  You use the same EPL whether the persistent layer is Oracle or flat files. 
My question should be – can I do the same thing using esper DB I/O adapter or do I have to write my own Adapter implementation?   Esper HA stores Event as blob and constructs event gain from blob efficiently. It would not be that difficult to replicate the similar logic by writing custom Adapter – I was hoping that someone must have already done this.

Comment: Actually EsperHA does not replay any events. EsperHA operates by storing the derived state only. For example "select count(*) from MyEvent" will store the count as a single long-type value and nothing else.

Comment: Only if your EPL statements utilize patterns that require an event to be part of the output, or when a data window such as a time window (a high resolution win), then Esper will save only those events that participate in an activate pattern or data window and only as long as such pattern subexpression or data window lives, after which it forgets and deletes such events.